# How to use redsocks to redirect all internet traffic to ssh tunnel?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables

I have an OpenWrt router with the IP of **192.168.1.1** and I wanna redirect all the internet traffic to my ssh tunnel, this is the ssh command that I use:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand corkscrew 127.0.0.1 3339 %h %p" -vND 1080 username@serverip
```

This is my `redsocks.conf` please correct this as well if there's any problem:

```
base {
        // debug: connection progress & client list on SIGUSR1
        log_debug = on;

        // info: start and end of client session
        log_info = on;

        /* possible `log' values are:
         *   stderr
         *   file:/path/to/file
         *   syslog:FACILITY  facility is any of "daemon", "local0"..."local7"
         */
        log = stderr;

        // detach from console
        daemon = off;

        /* Change uid, gid and root directory, these options require root
         * privilegies on startup.
         * Note, your chroot may requre /etc/localtime if you write log to syslog.
         * Log is opened before chroot & uid changing.
         */
        // user = nobody;
        // group = nobody;
        // chroot = "/var/chroot";

        /* possible `redirector' values are:
         *   iptables   - for Linux
         *   ipf        - for FreeBSD
         *   pf         - for OpenBSD
         *   generic    - some generic redirector that MAY work
         */
        redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {
        /* `local_ip' defaults to 127.0.0.1 for security reasons,
         * use 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen on every interface.
         * `local_*' are used as port to redirect to.
         */
        local_ip = 0.0.0.0;
        local_port = 12345;

        // `ip' and `port' are IP and tcp-port of proxy-server
        ip = 127.0.0.1;
        port = 1080;


        // known types: socks4, socks5, http-connect, http-relay
        type = socks5;

        // login = "foobar";
        // password = "baz";
}

redudp {                                                         
        // `local_ip' should not be 0.0.0.0 as it's also used for outgoing
        // packets that are sent as replies - and it should be fixed      
        // if we want NAT to work properly.                               
        local_ip = 127.0.0.1;                                             
        local_port = 10053;                                               

        // `ip' and `port' of socks5 proxy server.                        
        ip = 127.0.0.1;                                                   
        port = 1080;                                                      
        //login = username;                                               
        //password = pazzw0rd;                                            

        // kernel does not give us this information, so we have to duplicate it
        // in both iptables rules and configuration file.  By the way, you can 
        // set `local_ip' to 127.45.67.89 if you need more than 65535 ports to 
        // forward ;-)                                                         
        // This limitation may be relaxed in future versions using contrack-tools.
        dest_ip = 8.8.8.8;                                                        
        dest_port = 53;                                                           

        udp_timeout = 30;                                                         
        udp_timeout_stream = 180;                                                 
}                                                                                 

// you can add more `redsocks' and `redudp' sections if you need.
```

How can I use redsocks to redirect my internet traffic to that ssh tunnel ? I want it to be like openvpn where I can just connect to my wifi and browse the internet, with ssh tunnel I have to set the proxy to socks port 1080 on the client side every time I want to redirect all my internet traffic to that tunnel. I'm new to linux and I'm stuck at the iptables command, I have read the instructions at http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/ but I still can't get it to work. Please let me know the correct iptables command for my router above

Answer (score 2):

i am using the transocks, however the configuration for the iptables is the same:

Looks like that: https://gist.github.com/andersondanilo/a28e7165fa8a9700d8ead20a224ecf44

Your redsocks config looks ok.

My example is with transocks, however, they do the same thing.

Both transocks and redsocks will open one port on your net, you can redirect all trafic to that port, redsocks will redirect to the desired socks5 proxy

One suggested ip table configuration, that worked for me was:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Transocks: https://github.com/cybozu-go/transocks

set -e
stty -echoctl

# Point to the transparent socket port (running in an exclusive user)
TRANSOCKS_PORT=12345
TRANSOCKS_USER=transocks

# Redirect all the network of your computer (except transocks user)
REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK=1

# Redirect access point (wifi hotspot)
AP_SUBNET_ENABLED=1
AP_SUBNET_IFACE=ap0
AP_SUBNET_RANGE="192.168.12.0/24"

function action_up()
{
    echo "-----------------------------"
    echo "# Adding iptables chain rules"
    echo "-----------------------------"
    iptables -v -t nat -N TRANSOCKS
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 198.18.0.0/15 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TRANSOCKS_PORT

    if [ "$REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "--------------------------------"
        echo "# Redirecting non-transocks user"
        echo "--------------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner $TRANSOCKS_USER -j TRANSOCKS
    fi

    if [ "$AP_SUBNET_ENABLED" = 1 ]; then
        echo "-----------------------"
        echo "# Redirecting AP subnet"
        echo "-----------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -I PREROUTING -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -j TRANSOCKS
        iptables -v -I INPUT -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -p tcp -m tcp --dport $TRANSOCKS_PORT -j ACCEPT
    fi
}

function action_down()
{
    if [ "$REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "------------------------------"
        echo "# Cleaning non-transocks rules"
        echo "------------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner $TRANSOCKS_USER -j TRANSOCKS
    fi

    if [ "$AP_SUBNET_ENABLED" = 1 ]; then
        echo "--------------------------"
        echo "# Cleaning AP subnet rules"
        echo "--------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -D PREROUTING -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -j TRANSOCKS
        iptables -v -D INPUT -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -p tcp -m tcp --dport $TRANSOCKS_PORT -j ACCEPT
    fi

    echo "-----------------------------"
    echo "# Cleaning and removing chain"
    echo "-----------------------------"
    iptables -v -F TRANSOCKS -t nat
    iptables -v -X TRANSOCKS -t nat
}

trap 'action_down' SIGINT

action_up

echo
echo "Hit Ctrl+C to remove the ip table rules"
echo


while :
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Is that a solution for OP's problem, or a proposal of additional information to their question?

Comment: I am editing my answer, with more info